# included header for static library giving dllimport error

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries

I have the code presented later using Xerces-c, which can be built as a static or dynamic library.  Failing to include of course results in a compiler error, however when I add `#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>` visual studio 2012 gives me a linker errors saying:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const * const,char const * const,class xercesc_3_1::PanicHandler * const,class xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager * const)" (__imp_?Initialize@XMLPlatformUtils@xercesc_3_1@@SAXQBD0QAVPanicHandler@2@QAVMemoryManager@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate(void)" (__imp_?Terminate@XMLPlatformUtils@xercesc_3_1@@SAXXZ) referenced in function __catch$_main$0
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static char const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale" (__imp_?fgXercescDefaultLocale@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBDB)
```

Based on the `dllimport` part of the error it seems that it's failing to find a dll.  This is confirmed by that when I build Xerces-c as a dynamic library and link to it the error goes away.  However if I build Xerces-c as a static library and link to it the same error remains.  So my question is why am I getting an error asking for a dll when I'm including and linking to a static library?

```
using namespace xercesc;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);
    char c = inputFile.get();

  while (inputFile.good()) {
    std::cout << c;
    c = inputFile.get();
  }

  try {
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  }
  catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
    // Do your failure processing here
    return 1;
  }

  // Do your actual work with Xerces-C++ here.
  //XercesDOMParser parser;
  //parser.useScanner(XMLUni::fgDGXMLScanner);


  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

  // Other terminations and cleanup.
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your application with `XERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY` preprocessor macro to disable DLL import/export for Xerces library.

Also check that you link against static version of `.lib` files.